# How to create banner management in drupal 7

Tags: view, drupal-7, banner

I am using  Drupal 7, I have need to make a banner management system,
user only upload image file and add image title.
Image should be display on header section and sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the link on how to add banner http://www.bywombats.com/blog/06-08-2010/building-rotating-image-banner-views

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a content type for banner with image field.
2. Using views module create 2 blocks displaying only banner content type.
3. Assign block regions with one in the header region and the other in the sidebar
4. Provide adequate css or overwrite template file to get the desired look and feel.

Comment: Ashok How to define image  display in header or sidebar?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I dont understand your question fully.If the image in question is related to the banners, you can make use of the image field in views to display it. If sliders are required, you can make use of views slideshow. Custom modifications can be implemented by making use of template files. sorry if this late reply doesnt help.

Comment: Thanks Ashok for shareing use full knowledge.